# Efficient way of obtaining process information?

Tags: c, linux, process

I have looked at [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/). I was wondering if there are any major advantages to using [procps-ng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procps-ng/) instead. I am also open to suggestions for any other library that performs similar tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and "natural" way to get process information on Linux is thru the `/proc/` filesystem. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Remember that access to file under `/proc/` are quick (no real disk IO is involved).

Most of the files under `/proc` (e.g. `/proc/self/maps`) have a zero size as reported by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) but should be read sequentially (like you'll do on pipes).

The `procps` library (and `procps-ng`) wraps accesses to `/proc/`

Comment: I am looking for a library that wraps accesses to /proc/ to save me from some messy file I/O

Comment: @zztops The C standard library provides excellent solutions to that. `man 3 fopen`...

Comment: fopen won't parse the file for me

Comment: Which `/proc/` file do you want to access?

Comment: proc/[pid]/[most stuff in here]

Comment: Which precise file do you want to access in `/proc/$pid/` ? What is the `errno` after a failed `fopen` ? `procps` won't enable you to access resources that `fopen` or `open` don't access...